# Android Map: Map does not show up on Device

Tags: android, dictionary

I am able to see Map in emulator but once I load app on device map does not show up.

Emulator have target as google api 1.6 and device have android 1.6 loaded.

Is this diffrence causing issue?

please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Are you just seeing gray tiles? In that case it's almost definitely the API key that's wrong. The Emulator uses the `debug` keystore, with `androiddebugkey`, so you should create an API key for that. Remember to change it when you publish the app to the market =)

[Obtaining an API Key](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Answer (score 3):

While the problem is most likely the one that Mr. Hedlund suggested...if the built-in Google Maps application *also* does not work, it is likely to be a problem accessing the Google Maps tile server from the emulator over the Internet. You would need to discuss this with your IT department.

Comment: Now it is working. Key I have created using debug key store is fine.
After few install uninstall on Device app started working.Thank you guys for support.

Answer (score 3):

sorry i know its a dead topic but just wanted to add my experience with this;
u need the maps api key to be based off of the current keystore you are using
i had exported my project using a new keystore but a maps key generated from my old keystore.  once i used the new keystore to generate a new maps key everything worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with gray tiles, even though I had created/verified the API key, and had previously had the map working for some time. Turns out at some point, I edited the manifest file and moved the permissions lines. They apparently need to go BEFORE the application element. Thanks to Alan LaMielle ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809507/android-hello-mapview-tutorial-map-tiles-do-not-load/2123833#2123833)) for that solution!