# MapView works on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, google-maps, grid, android-mapview

I installed correctly google map api on my app, all works fine with the emulator. But when i transfer it to my phone it doesn't work anymore (there is that grid thing), and i can't find what's wrong.

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    MapView map ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        map.setSatellite(true);
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = map.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pins);
        HelloItem itemizedoverlay = new HelloItem(drawable, this);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class HelloItem extends ItemizedOverlay {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;

public HelloItem(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}
public HelloItem(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
    }

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return mOverlays.get(i);
}
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}
@Override
public int size() {
      return mOverlays.size();
}
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();
      return true;
    }
```

}

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809507/android-hello-mapview-tutorial-map-tiles-do-not-load

Comment: i did all this and it works fine with eclipse, but not on my phone.

Comment: yes, i did, but i'm gonna put all my code .

Comment: this is probably a dupe. This happens when you don't have a valid maps API key. Very common problem.

Comment: If tiles don't show up then the api key is wrong. If you export the app then it must have a release api key.

Comment: i took my MD5 certificate from the debug.keystore, and create a Google Map api key with it.

Comment: The debug keystore is only good for the emulator. You need to create a release keystore and API key

Comment: ok thanks, but how can i do that, do you have a link for a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you need to use different .keystore, one is for emulator(debug), one is for device(release). follow the same procedures when you acquired your debug.keystore MD5 & Map API Key from Google. this time you need to acquire both information for your_own.keystore, which is for release on device. then change the Map API Key in your map layout, the map will shown on your device then.