# Android Google maps glitch showing blank squares with x in the middle android

Tags: android, google-maps

Like i say in title my app is behaving strangely. It all worked fine until this morning... I changed some image in my app before uploading it onto market, and then i wanted to see once again whether everything is OK...Now i dont know what to do...see the image:

[image: MapView with Blank Squares]

And here is xml:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"                 
    android:enabled="false"                                     
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar1" 
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:apiKey="******-********************************" >              
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

Can anybody give some advice???

Comment: past here entire code so we can help you

Comment: yes entire code of class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I don't use mapView.setStreetView(true or false), but just use mapView.setSatelite (true) when i want to use Satelite view on the map, and set mapView.setSatelite.(false) when i want to use Street view...
I hope that this will help somebody else...
Once again thanks people for your time and help... :D

Answer (score 1):

I found this bug (setSatteliteView + setStreatView) as a specific for concrete android versions.
It exists on 2.2.1, but not on 2.3.5 (I have checked 2 different devices though)

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible bug in Google Maps that has popped up as recently as the past few weeks.

Someone else had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478952/mapview-rendering-with-tiles-missing-with-an-x-in-the-center).

[image]

In that case, the error was that both

```
mapView.setSatellite(true);
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

appeared in the code.  The documentation says that this is allowed, but in practice, it seems to be causing problems.  Look through your code to see if it contains both of those lines, and try commenting out one of them to see if it fixes things.

Comment: Your right...when i set Satellite to true squares don't appear...but when i change back they appear again(I have that option in settings)..

Comment: i gone through my code and i don't have both of mapView.set to true... 
onCreate i have this:
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  pogled = preferences.getString("list", "Street");
  
  if(pogled.equalsIgnoreCase("Street")){
   mapView.setSatellite(false);
   mapView.setStreetView(true);
  }else if (pogled.equalsIgnoreCase("Satelite")) {
   mapView.setSatellite(true);   
  }

Comment: Ok, for which of those two options are you getting these blank squares?  pogled == "Street" or pogled == "Satellite"?

Comment: I already had setSatellite(false) but changing setStreetView(true) to false fixed it for me. Not sure why I even made it true in the first place, I wasn't using it.

Comment: I think that this is just a error in maps api, but i did next: i just setSatelite true or false when i want a maps view to be Satelite or Street...i don't know why this is happening... :)
Thanks people for your help and time!!!!

Comment: So did you solve your problem?  If my answer solved it, you should mark it as accepted so that others with this same problem know how to fix it.  Or if my answer didn't solve it, you can add your own answer describing the steps you took to solve the problem and mark that one as accepted.