# Android: Map looks bad on device

Tags: android, google-maps

The map on my device looks bad, like in this image :

[image]

Any idea what causes this ?
Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bad internet connection perhaps? Because some tiles haven't loaded at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem found on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499706/android-google-maps-glitch-showing-blank-squares-with-x-in-the-middle-android)

Make sure code doesn't have both

```
mapView.setSatellite(..);
mapView.setStreetView(..);
```

if you want to display `streetView` just use

```
mapView.setSatellite(false);
```