# Android Map Cross Marks

Tags: android, maps

Why is this coming? i use eclipse and in that use the "export signed application" option. I use the existing keystore i.e. debug.keystore. I've got my own api key dev key, and have used it at all the proper places. The cross marks dont come all the time, but they do come often enough to look for a solution!
[image: the cross marks!!]

[image]

Comment: i've noticed a couple of threads on the same lines being closed due to their ambiguous nature, however this is definitely a problem

Comment: i have made use of map-view here, and i only want to test it on a real device, its not for production of any sort, how i know that its not an improper api key issue is that the grids dont come all the time, map many times loads pefectly

Comment: Have you tested on device? Its maybe due the emulator. Tiles do not load properly, of course.

Comment: yeah the pic is from device only

Comment: [Answer link][1] yippeeee!!! the answer is here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478952/mapview-rendering-with-tiles-missing-with-an-x-in-the-center

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the setSatellite() and setStreetView() methods from ur activity class if hv included them. that seems to be a bug in the mapView.