# Google Map Shows Crosses On Mapview

Tags: java, android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Map Cross Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519414/android-map-cross-marks)

I created a custom keystore. To use this I changed `debugkeystore` from `Window->Preferences->Android->Build` and for this keystore I got an api key from Google.

It works fine with satellite view but have some crosses over `mapView`, like this picture down below.

Am I missing something here?

[image: MapView]

**EDIT : ** As commented below duplicated questions  are [Android Map Cross Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519414/android-map-cross-marks) and
[MapView rendering with tiles missing with an "x" in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478952/mapview-rendering-with-tiles-missing-with-an-x-in-the-center)
It worked after changing `mapView.setSatellite(false)` instead of `mapView.setStreetView(true)`
And sorry for your stealing your valuable time.

Comment: duplicate 1 :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519414/android-map-cross-marks

duplicate 2 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478952/mapview-rendering-with-tiles-missing-with-an-x-in-the-center

Comment: BTW your answer is inside above duplicate question, it's good to search first buddy :). Save bandwidth lol

Comment: Thanks for your commented-answer. It worked when i changed `mapView.setSatellite(false)` instead of `mapView.setStreetView(true)`.