# Why does my android app shows google map with small boxes over the map?

Tags: android, google-maps, mapactivity

I am working on an android app. It was working correctly before but then I had to re-install my machine and I lost my debug.keystore. So I generated a new api key for the new debug.keystore but now I see map but with small grey boxes over the map. Any idea why this is happening and how to get rid of these boxes? BTW I am developing on a linux machine, Ubuntu 10.04 to be exact.
[image]

Comment: This will surely help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478952/mapview-rendering-with-tiles-missing-with-an-x-in-the-center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common suggestion that I have got is to dont use setStreeView(true) and setSatellite(true) together. Some have even suggested not to use setStreetView(true) altogether. But my code was working okay before. I had to reinstall my machine and therefore installed android SDK and other components afresh. So my guess is that this is an issue with some specific version But I have found out that this problem occurs specific revision of 2.2 - in my case Android SDK Platform 2.2, revision 3. I have tried running same code on 2.3 and it works correctly i.e no grey boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the .xml file with the maplayout?

And this might be caused if you have the

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
```

in your code, From my reading this is a bug in the Google Maps API Also if you didn't set the street view to true or any other view you should try setting it to false because i think it sets it to true by default.. But i recomend experiment little with the three views see which ones that gives you the white boxes and which ones that can be activated together and which ones that cannot..

Here is the three views if you want to experiment:

```
mapView.setStreetView(true);
mapView.setSatellite(true);
mainMap.setTraffic(true);
```