# Google Map is getting loaded with square patches

Tags: android, google-maps, android-widget

I am facing one problem ,that when the google map is loading then there i can see the square patches(as shown in the image).One thing i want to make u all clear that this is not because of low bandwidth of internet connection as i have tested it on a high bandwidth connection(4MBPS) too.
Also sometimes on clicking the map the patches gets disappeared(not always).
Please help me out asap.
Thanks in advance :)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vaibhav, I face the same problem in my app once. Please add some Layout code. I think you have make mistake in mapview Layout-width and Layout-Height attributes.

See this....

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="xxx"
    />
```

If you have used match parent or else instead of fill_parent then please change this. Hope your error would be resolved by this.

Comment: no i have used fill_parent but still i am getting the same problem...
any other suggestions please would be appreciated...
BTW thanks...

Comment: @Vaibhav can you please post some code snippet so I am able to found where the problem is....

Answer (score 1):

Quoting tdavisjr from [MapView rendering with tiles missing with an "x" in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478952/mapview-rendering-with-tiles-missing-with-an-x-in-the-center) :

> > Ok. After starting from a clean project I found these two lines of code that was the culprit.
>
> ```
> mapView.setSatellite(true);
>  mapView.setStreetView(true);
> ```
>
> They appeared back to back of each other
>   and I looked back at the very beginning of development and they were
>   there and it worked just fine. Apparently, this is a BUG in the
>   MapView as I'm guessing it tries to show both SateliteView and
>   StreetView at the same time. One would think that the latter would
>   override the former; but I guess not.
>
> So, the question I have is, why this all of the sudden surfaced just
>   within the last week or so. My guess is that the Maps Application was
>   last updated in the market on Sept 8th and maybe a day or so after
>   updating from the market, this issue started to resurface.
>
> As a test, can someone just add these two lines to their code and
>   confirm you get the same behavior?