# Android Offline Map Satilite View

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am implementing offline map using osmdroid & I completed the offline map's street view but the thing is i need to display the satellite view on offline Map. I am strucked on this point from last 2 weeks  so any one can help me to come out form this situation.The below link shows satilite view for Online Google Map But my requirement is offline map's Satilite VIew.

[MapView rendering with tiles missing with an "x" in the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478952/mapview-rendering-with-tiles-missing-with-an-x-in-the-center)

Advanced Thanks,
Murali.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps add-on for Android does not support offline maps of any form at this time, regardless of map tiles.