# Android - Bing Maps API demo crashes on execute

Tags: android, crash, bing-maps

I'm trying to learn to use the Bing Maps API for Android. I downloaded the SDK from the CodePlex site but the application seems to crash when I try to run it on my Eclipse emulator. I haven't touched the code at all so I'm wondering if there was a step I missed in the install/download or something.

Here's my LogCat.

```
06-11 15:26:27.760: D/dalvikvm(5092): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 51% free 2675K/5379K, external 1800K/2127K, paused 15ms
06-11 15:26:27.810: W/webcore(5092): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
06-11 15:26:27.840: D/gralloc_goldfish(5092): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-11 15:26:28.100: W/dalvikvm(5092): JNI WARNING: jarray 0xb6ceee40 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb6c70ac8 self=0x8ea4588
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   | sysTid=5101 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=149572152
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:91)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:108)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
06-11 15:26:28.100: I/dalvikvm(5092):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-11 15:26:28.100: E/dalvikvm(5092): VM aborting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Add GPU emulation in emulator. Open AVD Manager > choose emulator > edit > hardware section > new > GPU emulation > set to yes

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. Also, it seems SO is doing weird things with my LogCat. The only error logged is the last line: "E/dalvikvm(5092): VM aborting".

Comment: perhaps you need 4.0.3 emulator with revision 3 and higher, take a look at official docs

Comment: That made it run, sorta. It doesn't display a mapview of any sort. However, requiring 4.0.3 might be a problem. If I recall correctly, the lion's share of the Android OS distribution belongs to 2.3.3. Restricting myself to Android 4.0.3 just doesn't seem like a good plan.

Comment: But that's an issue for another question, so don't mind my rambling. I'd like to see if that mapview could get displayed first though.

Comment: gpu emulation require 4.0.3 emulator. But you can build against 4.0.3 and run on 2.3 device/emulator, you can build agains 2.3 and run on 4.0.3 device/emulator. About mapview, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809507/android-hello-mapview-tutorial-map-tiles-do-not-load